# How to install grub2 in windows 10/UEFI laptop

Tags: linux, boot, uefi, grub2

I'm trying to install openSUSE Leap 42.3 on my Lenovo Y600 laptop, dual boot with windows 10. It insists on booting windows, even after trying to re-install grub2. Perhaps the complicating factor is that I have a small SSD as the primary boot for windows, and Linux is installed on the hard drive.
Details:
1. Fiddle with bios to allow boot from DVD.
    - Boot mode: UEFI
    - Fast Boot: Disabled
    - USB Boot: Enabled
    - Move USB boot to occur before hard drive.
2. Install openSUSE (windows boots, no grub appears)
3. Follow guides at https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/html/book.opensuse.startup/cha.trouble.html#sec.trouble.data.recover.rescue.access section 16.6.2.3 to boot the system, and 16.6.2.4 to re-install grub.
When Linux is booted, I see that the SSD entries in /dev are nvme0, nvme0n1, and nvme0n1p1 through nvme0n1p4. The hard drive is the standard sda1 through sda7, with the root at sda7. Thus, I believe the correct command to install grub is
`grub2-install /dev/nvme0n1`
Doing this, windows boots after I exit.
If I boot the installation DVD and select "Boot from Hard Disk", I get
`error: not a valid boot device.`
What next?
Edit: [uefi boot not showing ubuntu / GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/1117803/uefi-boot-not-showing-ubuntu-grub?rq=1) seemed like it might be helpful, but no. efibootmgr seemed to create a new entry, but it did nothing. And the entry was gone next time I booted to Linux.

Edit: I gave up. To install and boot Linux, I modify the bios to turn off UEFI. To get back to windows, I modify the bios again to enable UEFI.

Comment: Grub should have been installed already and in the correct place (EFI partition). Check the boot order, not just drives and try to select OpenSUSE instead of "Windows boot manager". If it boots all you may need to do is update Grub, not reinstall.

Comment: I don't understand. I have no choices when I boot. Windows. Period. In the bios, I have the choice of Windows Boot Manger or (if a bootable device is found) USB.

Comment: Is your Windows 10 install configured for UEFI or legacy boot? Is there an efi partition on the SSD?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10 is UEFI. There is an EFI partition on the SSD (as well as an EFI partition on the hard drive added by openSUSE) At one point, I installed Linux in legacy mode. That worked fine, but then I couldn't access windows. Or is there a way to do that?